# Blank fragment in navigation tab with async task - Android

Tags: android, tabs, android-asynctask, fragment, listadapter

I'm currently developing an android app which uses navigation tabs on the homescreen. 
Tab 1 contains a list fragment which is populated over an async task. However, when I start my app, I only see a blank screen ([see screenshot](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3494/wz47dghr_jpg.htm)).

The problem is that the listfragment gets created before the async task has finished.
Therefore, the information in the list is shown only after changing tabs and reselecting tab 1. Can I somehow force this behaviour without actually clicking a tab?

I have tried several things in the onpostexecute() method like setting the list adapter there, calling notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter or calling the oncreate method of the fragment to somehow refresh it - but no success.
I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

*Relevant code snippets:*

My **Homescreen.class** with the navigation tabs and the async task that populates the list:

```
public class Homescreen extends ActionBarActivity implements ListListFragment.Callbacks {

public static ArrayList<Places> places = new ArrayList<Places>();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
String tab_label1;
TabListener<ListListFragment> t1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new RetrievePlacesActivity().execute();

    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    tab_label1 = getResources().getString(R.string.tab_1);
    Tab tab1 = bar.newTab().setText(tab_label1)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_view_as_list);
    t1 = new TabListener<ListListFragment>(this, tab_label1,
            ListListFragment.class);
    tab1.setTabListener(t1);
    bar.addTab(tab1);
    // do the same with tab2 and tab3

    Fragment.instantiate(this, ListListFragment.class.getName());
}

private class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> cls) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = cls;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment == null) { 
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}

public class RetrievePlacesActivity extends
        AsyncTask<Void, Integer, JSONArray> {

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Do a Http-Get Request and read the results into a JSONArray
            JSONArray res = new JSONArray(result);
            return res;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        // Get the JSON objects from jsonArray
        // With the information of these objects create instances of class "Places"
        // Add these places to an ArrayList called "places"
    }
}
}
```

And a small part of my **ListListFragment.class** which accesses the ArrayList "places" in Homescreen.class and uses a custom adapter to populate the listview:

```
public class ListListFragment extends ListFragment {

public interface Callbacks {
    public void onItemSelected(String id);
}

public ListListFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    PlacesAdapter adapter = new PlacesAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.list_line, Homescreen.places);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```